# Seeing console progress messages in Shake

Tags: shake-build-system

I am using Shake, calling `wget` to download a file. If I do that on the command line I see a one-line progress bar, but when called from Shake I see many lines of dots. As an example:

```
shake shakeOptions $
    action
       (cmd "wget http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/index.tar.gz" :: Action ())
```

I would like that to show the one-line progress bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

```
shake shakeOptions{shakeLineBuffering=False} $
    action
        (cmd "wget http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/index.tar.gz --progress=bar:force" :: Action ())
```

There are two things going on here:

1) `wget` detects that it isn't sending direct to the console (since `cmd` captures output using pipes), and turns off the progress bar. With `wget`, you can turn that back on with `--progress=bar:force`.

2) Once I've done that, the progress bar doesn't actually display,
because Shake turns on line buffering by default (it helps commands run in parallel show less interleaved output) and a progress bar only updates within
one line. You can fix that by setting the option
`shakeLineBuffering=False`.